# JavaScript how to store Fetch data to a global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables, fetch-api

I'm making a currency convert app that is using an API. When I fetch to the API the `data` variable has the JSON that I need. But when I store it to a the global variable, and `console.log` that, the output is `null`.

**CODE:**

```
const API_URL = 'SECRET';

let currency_json = null;

//Makes the request
async function getJSONdata(url) {
    loading.style.display = '';

    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data); //Outputs the JSON. For some reason it gives null
            currency_json = data;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    loading.style.display = 'none';   

}

//Calls the function
getJSONdata(API_URL);

console.log(currency_json); //Outputs null
```

Also it doesn't give any errors. And I have read another person's solution on another website (To add Timeout somewhere), problem is they didn't said where or how to put it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making an `async` call. Fetch gets data, but it is not available right away.

You need to wait for data to be available. Inside `then` you wait for it to be available and that's why it's working.

You could use async/async, but it seems you're making the call at a module level and that's not available there. You should move your code to execute from inside the promise callback (then method).

What you've heard about `setTimeout` is a form of `long polling`, you could implement it something like this

```
const longPollCallback = () => {
 if (currency_json) {
  console.log(currency_json)
 } else {
  setTimeout(longPollCallback, 500)
 }
}

setTimeout(longPollCallback, 500)
```

But you should rely on `then`, `async/await` instead of long polling.

Comment: sorry to ask but I'm new... I kind of don't know what this all means, if you wouldn't mind, can you please show me? I would really appreciate it

Comment: what if the data is not available even after 500 due to some network issue??

Comment: That's why the callback registers itself again.